# using std::vector<std::string*> and std::vector<std::ofstream*>

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create of `vector` of four `string` objects,and four `ofstream` objects, the `string` objects are used to name the output files and the `ofstream` objects are used to write the data.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<std::string*> myFileNames; 
std::vector<std::ofstream*> myFiles;
int id[4]={1,2,3,4};

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   myFiles.push_back(new std::ofstream);
   myFileNames.push_back(new std::string);

}

int tmp[4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{

     tmp[i] = id[i] ;
    myFileNames[i] = "file";
    myFileNames[i] += tmp[i];
    myFileNames[i] += " .csv ";

    std::cout<< "Opening file:" << myFileName[i] << std::endl;
    myFiles[i].open (myFileNames[i].c_str());
    myFiles[i]<< "a,";
 }
```

The question is that from this line --`myFileNames[i] = "file";` the errors happen, it seems I can't give the values to `myFileNames` member in this way, could anyone help me with this, like I want to create four files with four different names, and give them values in a loop.

Comment: You don't want vectors of pointers. Use `std::vector<std::string>` and `std::vector<std::ofstream>` instead. To create the objects, use `myFiles.push_back(std::ofstream())` and `myFileNames.push_back("")`. The rest should work fairly as-is, at first glance.

Comment: You're assigning a `const char*` to a vector element referencing a `std::string*`. What did you expect, the compiler would generate what you *meant* it to do? (and there is *no* reason to be using a vector of `std::string*` pointers to begin with).

Comment: @zneak: Streams are not copyable (so you can't put them in a vector).

Comment: @LokiAstari, streams aren't copyable but they're movable, so `push_back(std::ofstream())` should work on a conforming implementation.

Comment: @zneak. Yep just had to upgrade gcc, but now it works. Note to user-2647095. Note you need to make sure you are using the latest version of the language not all compilers do so out of the box you may need to specify the correct flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFileNames[i]`, according to your declaration, is not a string object but a pointer to string. I'm not sure why it was declared this way. 
Make it 
`std::vector<std::string> myFileNames;`
`std::vector<std::ofstream> myFiles;`
with no pointers.

You should also remove the for loop with the calls to push_back, since you don't need to store anything in them yet.

Comment: Note that iostreams are noncopyable so it will error as soon as you try to push back an `std::ofstream`.

Comment: @JesseGood: It will work in C++11 if you push back an r-value, since they are moveable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: True, although libstdc++ still hasnt added move constructors to its iostreams yet (don't know what the OP is using though)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I just tried and does not seem to work. `g++-4.7 -std=c++11`. Neither does `emplace_back()`

Comment: Sorry if I made some stupid mistakes, 'cause it's the first time I program with c++, thank you all for the help.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Then that's a problem with the implementation, because `basic_ofstream` is certainly supposed to be moveable (27.9.1.11/4). And `vector<T>::push_back` is supposed to have an overload which takes an `T&&`, and which has no requirement that `T` be copyable, but only move insertable (23.2.3/16).  It works in VS11, at least.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: So it does `g++-4.8 -std=c++11` works fine.

Comment: I still have some problems, when I run the program(modified as you told), it has errors about the vector range, "expression: vector subscript out of range"@Zach Stark